VS Code equivalent of emacs guide-key?
Is there a VS Code extension or other trick which provides the equivalent of emacs guide-key?  In other words, something which when you press a prefix key like Ctrl+k, it automatically popups up a modal window listing all the key bindings beginning with that prefix key?
Motivation
This is very useful for helping you find the binding you are looking for, and also for discovering and memorising other bindings.  For example, with guide-key in emacs, if you press Ctrl+x r which is the prefix for all commands relating to rectangles and registers, you see the lower panel in this screen, which could helpfully remind you that Ctrl+x r k is the shortcut for killing (cutting) a rectangle, but simultaneously teach you that Ctrl+x r t is the shortcut for filling a rectangle with a string of your choice:

Non-solutions
I found a few extensions which are close to what I want but unfortunately none of them are solutions.
For example, the WhichKey extension seems to be for building a multi-tier menu of groups of commands all accessible from a single "leader key" shortcut.  This is part of VSpaceCode built for people who like the Spacemacs approach to key bindings, where Space is the leader key for many commands.
However, while I'm looking for a similar UI visually, I want one which can provide this kind of UI automatically for all existing prefix (leader) keys, not just a single one.  By "automatically", I mean it can auto-generate the menus based on existing keybindings.  This is what guide-key does.  I found https://github.com/kvoon3/vscode-which-key-config-gen which can auto-generate, but again that seems to be designed for use with whichkey which assumes there is only one leader key.
I also found LeaderMode and Leader Key, but again they assume a single leader key like with Spacemacs.
